# can my code improve from using LINQ?

Tags: arrays, vb.net, linq

I have this code, which works fine, but is slow on large datasets.

I'd like to hear from the experts if this code could benefit from using Linq, or another method, and if so, how?

```
  Dim array_of_strings As String()

  ' now I add strings to my array, these come from external file(s). 
  ' This does not take long

 ' Throughout the execution of my program, I need to validate millions
 ' of other strings.

  Dim search_string As String
  Dim indx As Integer

  ' So we get million of situation like this, where I need to find out
 ' where in the array I can find a duplicate of this exact string

  search_string = "the_string_search_for"

  indx = array_of_strings.ToList().IndexOf(search_string)
```

Each of the strings in my array are unique, no duplicates.

This works pretty well, but like I said, too slow for larger datasets. I am running this query millions of times. Currently it takes about 1 minute for a million queries but this is too slow to my liking.

Comment: Why are you calling `ToList()`?  You should be able to just do `indx = array_of_strings.IndexOf(search_string)`.

Comment: In any case if you want to see where your code is slow get a decent profiler and measure it.  Linq is not meant to improve performance, it is meant to improve productivity be reducing the number of loops to have to code.

Comment: creating a temp List "millions of times" -- maybe it ought to be a list?

Comment: Are you familiar with Big O notation? It's a nerdy way of evaluating how long an algorithm takes. I believe searching through a list is O(n).

Comment: Thanks D Stanley, I'll fix that and report back on any performance improvement.

Comment: D Stanley, That does throw an error:Error BC30516 Overload resolution failed because no accessible 'IndexOf' accepts this number of arguments.

Comment: @Stanley Ok, fixed the syntax: 'indx = array.IndexOf(array_of_strings,searchstring)' but that has not made a huge impact..

without ToList:
25-Feb-16 8:04:50 AM Starting Process
25-Feb-16 8:08:42 AM Process finished

with ToList
25-Feb-16 7:13:44 AM Starting Process
25-Feb-16 7:18:23 AM Process finished

Comment: summary: `'indx = array.IndexOf(array_of_strings,searchstring)` takes 3:40 on my sample dataset, also when I create the list once outside the loop and perform the search directly on the established list, takes 3:40. Running it on the array directly takes 3:52.     I am looking for ways to make this take a couple of seconds instead. How fast can one perform list/array searches? Should I store my data as something else in the array (is a search on binary faster than a search on strings?).

Comment: @Yeahson have you tried this with a SortedSet? I'd be astounded if that didn't improve performance significantly. In fact, if it doesn't I guarantee your problem is somehow different from how you've described it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's no need to use Linq.
If you used an indexed data structure like a dictionary, the search would be O(log n), at the cost of a slightly longer process of filling the structure. But you do that once, then do a million searches, you're going to come out ahead.

See the description of Dictionary at this site:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7y3x785f(v=vs.110).aspx

Since (I think) you're talking about a collection that is its own key, you could save some memory by using `SortedSet<T>`
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd412070(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: I'll look into that. Any pointers on how to do a quick fix fo the above code?

Comment: I've done it with `dictionary`, but this has slowed down the process. I haven't used a `SortedSet` yet. I have my data sorted in another way that assist further processing, it's a logic order with regards to XY location, so loosing that would be a pity.

Comment: So, you're saying that exchanging the Array of strings for a Dictionary has caused an overall performance decrease? I'd be quite surprised by that. Either there aren't as many data as you say, or the workload is much fewer searches. Big-O Algorithmic analysis is a very old area of computer science (because this stuff used to matter a lot).

Comment: SortedSet is designed for your particular use case, as you don't have to reorder the set to add new values (Dictionary has to move existing records around, I think).

Comment: Are you saying there are two different ways you need your data sorted? What is the time component involved in sorting the set by the XY location?

Comment: If there's a good reason to keep it in the existing order, I'd say leave it in that order and make a copy of it as a SortedSet and just do the queries against the sorted Set. You'll be sacrificing memory for time, which is a typical tradeoff.

Answer (score 0):

No, I don't think it can benefit from linq.
Linq queries are slow, relatively speaking.
You might try to multithread it, however.

Comment: "Linq queries are slow" compared to what?  How would multithreading help?

Comment: They're slow compared to not using linq. All my tests show these results. Have you ever done any comparisons of your own? I'm interested in seeing other people's results.

Comment: Multithreading could help by searching half of the array in one thread, and the other half in another thread. This already reduces execution speed.

Comment: The issue with this answer is that there are other approaches that solve this problem without the complexity of multithreading.

Comment: Multithreading doesn't have to be complex with the TPL. While your answer is easier, I was trying to answer in a way that wouldn't add execution time to the initialization phase. The best solution, isn't always the easiest.

Comment: Insertion into a List is O(1), insertion into a self-balancing tree is O(log n). Search in a list is O(n) (multi-threading doesn't change that), but in a tree is O(log n). Given the task parameters: load once, search millions of times, I think my answer is vastly superior.

Comment: That said, you didn't deserve minuses.

Comment: All linq queries add is a wrapper that enumerates the underlying collection.  It should not be significantly slower that an _equivalent_ `foreach` loop that generates the same results.  If you have a linq query that's _significantly_ slower than a `foreach` then the linq query is not equivalent to the `foreach`.  Saying "Linq is slow" without any context is false.  Multithreading is slow too (compared to not multithreading)  in many situations.

Comment: Yes, the next step will be multi-treading, but I wanted to make sure to multi-thread an optimal solution, not an average one ...